# Can't we award bounty to a helpful answer directly?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

This may be a duplicate. Sometimes, I stumble upon answers/questions that help me save time so much that I feel like awarding a direct bounty to that answer, as a sign of gratitude to the answerer or sheer appreciation of the cleverness of the answer. I feel +1 is not enough in these cases.

Can I directly go and attach/award a bounty to an answer? I didn't find any option to do so under the upvote/downvote buttons. If this option isn't there, wouldn't it be nice to have this feature?

Comment: Yes. Set a bounty on the question using the reason that goes something like "reward currently existing answer", wait two days, and reward it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As is covered in the [How Does the Bounty System Work FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/253560), the way to use a bounty to reward an old answer is to:

1. Create a new bounty, selecting the "Reward Existing Answer" option.
2. Wait at least 24 hours.
3. Manually award the bounty to the answer you want to reward.

Removing the 24-hour limit on the bounties with the "Reward Existing Answer" option has been discussed on meta before, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107282/253560) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116072/253560). Some of the motivations that have been stated for keeping the limit are:

1. It prevents unthrottled transfer of reputation.
2. It gives other users a chance to provide an even better answer.
3. It draws attention to exemplary answers.