# Awarding a bounty to a good answer which is not necessarily a complete answer

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question and I would like to give a bounty to an answer post which does not provide a complete answer but is helpful and which took some time for the poster to provide. The only other answer is not an answer at all.

Are there any rules or guidelines that address the idea of providing a bounty to someone who posted a helpful answer if it it is not a complete answer?

I see so many posted answers where people seem to go to so little trouble and I would like to award this user.

And is the following procedure correct? I plan to create a bounty for a duration of one day and then manually award it.

Or is there some other way that I can convey some of my reputation to another person's answer?

Comment: this stackoverflow has a more detailed procedure of assigning a bounty to an existing answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306182/cant-we-award-bounty-to-a-helpful-answer-directly?rq=1 and there is this question on ethics of bounty awarding on incomplete answers http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267376/ethics-on-bounty-award-when-best-answer-only-solved-half-of-the-problem?rq=1